# How to read from a stream you've just written to without calling Flush() in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, memorystream, c#-7.0

I have some code that uses a 3rd party library, EDIFabric, which writes to a stream, which I need to capture that output and use it to return a string by way of a StreamReader.

```
    // Build out the memory stream we'll use to conver to a string.
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new X12Writer(stream))
        {
            writer.Write("Write EDI values to the stream"); // Not valid EDI output...

            writer.Flush();
            // Flush() is obsolete and generates a CS0618 compiler warning, "Type or member is obsolete"

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Return to the beginning of the stream
        }

        using StreamReader reader = new(stream);

        // If I omit the flush, the returned string is empty
        return reader.ReadToEnd(); // Returns the stream as a string
    }
```

Any suggestions that don't include using Flush()?

Comment: Move `stream.Seek` out of the inner `using` block.  The disposal of `writer` at the end of its `using` block should flush `writer` for you. That assumes that `X12Writer` is properly implemented. I assume they obsoleted `Flush` because you're expected to use a `using` block. There are too many bad examples out there where people use `Flush` and `Close` on streams and writers because they don't have `using` blocks.

Comment: @madreflection This did the trick. Do you want to add it as an answer so you can get credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was derived from @madreflection's comment above, simply moving the `stream.Seek()` out of the inner `using` block.

```
// Build out the memory stream we'll use to conver to a string.
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new X12Writer(stream))
    {
        writer.Write("Write EDI values to the stream"); // Not valid EDI output...
    }
    
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd(); // Returns the stream as a string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't read data from a stream until the writer (for that stream) committed its changes to the stream. Some writers allow committing all the buffered data at any point, but not all - often data formats supported by writers require a particular block size or some other restrictions limiting how much partial data can be written to the stream.

If you need to get complete data - your safest option is to dispose the writer and either seek the stream to start (as code in the question shows) or create a new stream over the same data (writers are not required to support "leave the stream open" option in a constructor to my knowledge). I have no knowledge of the `X12Writer` class, but it is possible they don't want one to call `Flush` for reasons above and whole stream should be committed at once to produce a valid result.

```
// re-creating a stream from a disposed memory stream.  
var freshStream = new MemoryStream(srteam.ToArray());
```

If you fine with partial data - check out questions about "C# tee stream" like [Redirect writes to a file to a stream C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321578/redirect-writes-to-a-file-to-a-stream-c-sharp) to capture data as it is being committed to the stream.