# Saving XML to a File while reading it with XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I receive XML in an HTTP response. I want to parse it with XmlReader because it's rather large and has many child nodes. But in the same time I want to be able to save the whole XML to a file.

How can I do this without first reading the whole XML to a memory buffer?

Also, I do not always parse XML to the last element, but I need to save whole XML.

Thank you

Comment: if you want to save the whole file locally there is no other way that downloading it all to the machine where your code runs. If you load till the middle only to save on the bandwidth, how do you imagine to save it all locally on disk?!?!

Comment: @DavidePiras XmlReader reads XML using Stream. I thought that maybe it is somehow possible to write the content of the response while reading it with XmlReader. In parallel. If I stop to read the file with XmlReader in the middle, then I want to be able to save the rest. I want to use XmlReader not for saving of bandwidth, but for parsing speed, and for memory (because XmlReader does not require loading of the whole XML into memory)

Comment: How do you receive the data exactly?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I receive data via HTTP. I get a Stream using HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream. Using this Stream I create a StreamReader, then, using the StreamReader I create an XmlReader.

Comment: Maybe something like what's discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1055872/60761

Answer (score 1):

Why not push the incoming stream straight to a file and then parse the XML in the file afterwards using XmlReader?

Comment: I think it's not good for performance. You first write it, then you read it again. Our system will make very man requests

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong, you can use XmlWriter.WriteNode method,

```
XmlTextWriter empwriter = new XmlTextWriter ();

    //Write the start tag.
    empwriter .WriteStartElement("Employee");

    //Write the first employee.
    empwriter .WriteNode(reader, false);

         //all your elements.. 

    //Write the last employee.
    empwriter.WriteNode(reader, false);
    empwriter.WriteEndElement();
```

[XML Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a streamwriter and write node-by-node as you need it.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
{
        //Start loop to read XML here

    writer.Write("XML node you want to write");     
        // Loop ends
}
```