# Dispose Stream While Still in Use by an Asynchronous Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, stream, dispose

I have a fairly big `stream` (represents an image). I have two tasks to do:

1. I want to upload the stream to the cloud using an async method (I assume the method is backed by `Task.Run`)
2. While the stream is being uploaded, I need to locally read the stream (in order to create a thumbnail out of the image).

My question is: Since the same stream object is referenced by two pointers in two different asynchronous tasks, where should I dispose the stream? Can I detect the number of pointers referencing a stream? or at least can I detect whether the stream is being in use (even by another thread) before disposing it?

I don't know which of the two tasks finishes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your implementation is thread safe and you really need to use a disposable from multiple places you can use [RefCountDisposable](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/disposables) from ReactiveExtensions (Rx). Eg:

```
RefCountDisposable refDisposable = new RefCountDisposable(stream);     
IDisposable ref1 = refDisposable.GetDisposable();
IDisposable ref2 = refDisposable.GetDisposable();
```

When both `ref1` and `ref2` are disposed `stream` will be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

1) If it is backed by `Task.Run` that is a horrible implementation of a uploader. There are truly asynchronous methods to do IO calls and the library should be using that.

2) `Stream` is not thread safe, you can not have two threads touching the same stream at the same time. What you need to do is open two streams to the same file while passing in [`FileShare.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) in to the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx), one for your thumbnail, one for your upload. Now both sets of processes can dispose of their own stream when they are done with it.

Comment: Regarding 2, I have no files, it's kind of memory stream (coming from an uploader control). I'm trying to prevent copying the stream.

Comment: Then you use two `MemoryStream`s pointing to the same `byte[]`. [This constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx) does not copy the `byte[]` both streams will use the same array as their backing store.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It's actually HttpPostedFile.InputStream (which is just a stream)

Comment: Then you will need to write (or find) a custom `Stream` class that splits the stream and buffers the data for the slower of the two readers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055872/how-can-i-split-copy-a-stream-in-net for more info.