# How can I set StreamWriter's source as multiple in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, logging, streamwriter

I am developing some network program in .NET.
I want to see entire text stream on my output window as log.
So I tried to search the solution for setting mutiple source on StreamWriter.
But I can not find that.
I want these style like below not extension method :

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream, traceStream)
```

or

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
sw.setSecondStream(traceStream);
```

Comment: Related, but no concrete answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055872/)

Comment: It seems to me that you're looking for a Tee Stream. Warning: Such an arrangement could potentially have unbounded memory requirements (if one stream writes faster than the other). Here's an implementation that blocks rather than buffers: http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/tee-stream-in-csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be so hard to make a stream splitter. For a Write-only stream without Seek functions it's pretty simple.

The constructor call would then look like

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(new WriteStreamSplitter(socketStream, traceStream));
```

and the class (untested, just a mock up)

```
class WriteStreamSplitter : Stream
{
    public WriteStreamSplitter(Stream a, Stream b)
    {
        _streamA = a;
        _streamB = b;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _streamA.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        _streamB.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanRead  { get { return false; } }

    // trivial overloads of all other abstract members, 
    // they are allowed to throw NotImplemented


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Maybe it's best to do nothing here but a StreamWriter 
            // assumes 'ownership' of the wrapped stream, 
            // so if we want to continue that pattern:

            // the guidelines say these shouldn't throw
            _streamA.Dispose();
            _streamB.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there is no storage overhead here and the Write will just block.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a different approach. Create a class and aggregate a StreamWriter. Then use MyStreamWriter to write to the stream instead of directly use a StreamWriter:

```
class MyStreamWriter
{
   private StreamWriter sw;

   // Constructor
   public MyStreamWriter(Stream socketStream)
   {
      sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
   }

   // Example function
   public void WriteLine(string myText)
   {
     Trace.WriteLine(myText);
     sw.WriteLine(myText);
   }
}
```

This allows you to attach additional functionality.

Instead of using your code to create an instance of the StreamWriter you would simply create a *MyStreamWriter*:

```
var sw = new MyStreamWriter(socketStream);
```

I use the Trace class to log the message instead of writing it to another stream. Components like [log4net](https://github.com/apache/log4net) allow to log all calls to the Trace (or Debug) class and route it to a log-file / SQL-Server / whatever. This way you would have a much more flexible solution.

As a alternative you could implement a [TraceListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx) by yourself which could simply add all of your output to a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Henk. Good Idea!

But I change a little. I need just log fuctionality, so I added log concept. It based on your splitter idea.

## loggable stream classs

```
public class LoggableStream : Stream
{
    private Stream _stream;
    private Encoding _textEncoding;



    public LoggableStream(Stream stream, Encoding textEncoding)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _textEncoding = textEncoding;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return _stream.CanRead;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get
        {
            return _stream.CanSeek;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return _stream.CanWrite;
        }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _stream.Length;
        }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _stream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            _stream.Position = Position;
        }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _stream.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var result = _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        try
        {
            var log = this._textEncoding.GetString(buffer, offset, count);
            Trace.TraceInformation("READ : " + log);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        var result = _stream.Seek(offset, origin);
        return result;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _stream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);

        try
        {
            var log = this._textEncoding.GetString(buffer, offset, count);
            Trace.TraceInformation("WRIT : " + log);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

## usage

```
using (var netStream = _controlClient.GetStream())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(new LoggableStream(netStream, Encoding.UTF8)))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new LoggableStream(netStream, Encoding.UTF8)))
{
    var readLine = sr.ReadLine();
    sw.WriteLine("hello");
}
```