# How to split a Filestream into two substreams

Tags: c#

Is there a way to split a filestream which is obtained via

```
File.Open("100GB.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

into 2 equally sized substreams?
I would like to upload the file partially to a website, but the webserver has limitations on the maximum filesize allowed for posting.
Two streams are necessary to simultaneously upload the parts to the website.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could Google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055872/how-can-i-split-copy-a-stream-in-net

Comment: @Sach: If we just needs to read a fraction at a time the implementation is more simple than what your link proposes

Answer (score 2):

If the website doesn't provide a multi-part upload mechanism, just read N bytes into different streams:

```
using (var fs = File.Open("100GB.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    var chunkSizeInBytes = ...; // whatever you like, below code assumes it's evenly divisible into your 100GB file
    var numChunks = fs.Length / chunkSizeInBytes;
    var buf = new byte[chunkSizeInBytes];
    for (int i = 0, bufIndex = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, bufIndex += chunkSizeInBytes) 
    {
        fs.Read(buf, bufIndex, chunkSizeInBytes);
        // if, for whatever reason, you actually need a new stream, 
        // just create a MemoryStream and use fs.CopyTo(stream, size)
        PostMyData(buf);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Urrm i forgot to tell you that i want to upload them simultaneously to cut off the time needed for uploading. For that reason, i need 2 or more streams which derive from the root stream.

Comment: @AllCowsAreBurgers: No you don't; you just need to setup your buffer offsets beforehand and spin up a few threads (tasks). Reading is thread safe as far as I'm aware. Sure you can create multiple streams as well, just created them, set up the offsets, and use `CopyTo`.  Adding parallelism to the code already here isn't a big shift, the idea is the same. I don't see any need to get into complex stream management stuff here