# c# clone Stream object

Tags: c#, stream, clone

I want to clone stream object. This is my code:

```
var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0) {
 byte[] data;
 using(Stream inputStream = fileContent.InputStream) {
  MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
  if (memoryStream == null) {
   memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
  }
  data = memoryStream.ToArray();
 }
}
```

after copying my the content to "data" variable, "`fileContent.InputStream`" will have lenght=0. How can I copy content to the "data" byte array and have still the content in "`fileContent.InputStream`" ? I tried to clone somehow the "fileContent.InputStream" before using, but I didn't manage.

Here is my full code. The content is a license file for my application and I have a class which is in charge with validation of file. This class can decrypt and validate it. This receives as param a byte array. I want to clone the stream in order to create a byte array(and validate it), if is valid I want to save the "fileContent.InputStream" as a license file. This is the reason why I want somehow to clone the stream.

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
                if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    byte[] data;
                    using (Stream inputStream = fileContent.InputStream)
                    {
                        var memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                        if (memoryStream == null)
                        {
                            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                            inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        }
                        data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                    var decryptor = new LicenseEncryptorDecryptor();
                    decryptor.DecryptLicense(data);
                    if (decryptor.InvalidFile)
                    {
                        return Json(new {InvalidFile=true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }

                    new FilesManager().SaveFile(fileContent.InputStream, fileContent.FileName, EFileType.License, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just copy `data`?

Comment: When I use "inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);"  then "inputStream" became empty having length=0

Comment: What is your final goal with this snippet?

Comment: Looks like XY-problem. Why do you think you need to clone a stream?

Comment: Before I save the file, I want to check if content is valid, if is valid i want to save the file, if not i want to return an error message\

Comment: You can still use `File.WriteAllText()` after you read the stream you know?

Comment: @Meikel is right, there is no need to read stream twice. All data already in `data`. Validate and save with `File.WriteAllBytes()`.

Comment: I have edited the post in order to explain why I need to create somehow a clone of the stream

Comment: Related - [How can I split (copy) a Stream in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1055872/15498)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how is my question related with that?? My question has nothing to do with spliting, I want somehow to create a clone the "fileContent.InputStream" before using

Comment: Because if you read it, they describe it as wanting to end up with two streams that both return the same data that the original stream has - is that not also a description of your problem? If you're tying to work generically with streams, you should realise that some streams are forward-only so copy and re-wind cannot work for *all* streams.

Comment: images of code are useless, why not copy-paste?

Comment: @vasily.sib I think is irrelevant that if I copy+paste or I add an image with full part of the code

Comment: I can't copy-paste a code from your image, when I composing an answer. Actualy I even can't see your image because of my network policy. It is also a reason for downvote your question, look [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @vasily.sib I admit you are right, now I have edited my question and I have replaced my image with copy+paste of the code

Comment: Your copy-pasted code already contains a solution. Converting `byte[]` to `MemoryStream` is fine. You just need to cleanup your code.